# ¿Como guardar las sublistas de una lista en otra lista nueva? (Python)

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Tengo `list` la cual a su vez tiene almacenadas otras sublistas y también tengo declarada `secondList`.

Lo que quiero lograr hacer es el proceso de guardar cada sublista de `list` en `secondList`, de manera que si por ejemplo ejecuto `print('secondList[0] = ', secondList[0])`, la salida fuera tipo `secondList[0] = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]`, y así sucesivamente con los demás índices de `secondList`.

Lo que tengo de código es esto:

```
list = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], 
         ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13'], 
         ['14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']]

secondList = []

for i in range(0, len(list)):
    secondList.append(list[i])

print('SecondList[0] = ', secondList[0])
```

Con dicho código la salida que tengo en consola es `secondList[0] =  ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`, cuando realmente la salida que quiero obtener es `secondList[0] = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]`

Espero y alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Basta con hacer: `secondList.append([list[i]])`. Saludos

Comment: Evita usar `list` como nombre de variable. Es una palabra reservada (Es el constructor de listas, además de usarse para anotaciones de tipo de datos).

Comment: No entiendo por qué esperas otro par de corchetes en la salida. Si `secondList` ha de ser una copia de `list`, entonces `secondList[0]` sería una lista con los numeros, y no una lista con otra lista dentro.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Me funciono correctamente tu respuesta, muchas gracias!